# Write a function that can take individual numbers, a list of numbers, or a pandas dataframe and find the mean

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that can find the mean across multiple data types.

The below function works to find the mean for given numbers:

```
def mean(self, *numbers):
    sum = 0
    for x in numbers :
        sum += x
    return(sum / len(numbers))
```

However, I cannot seem to figure out how to get the function to work for multiple data types. I attempted to use `**kwargs` to define a "list" or a "pd.dataframe" but continued to get errors.

Comment: If a single argument is passed, it would be received as `numbers[0]`.

Comment: The simplest is to check type of `x` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I can find 2 simple way to achieve what u want:

1. First way is to dadding a sort of wrapper:

```py
import pandas as pd

def mean_iter(numbers):
    sum = 0
    for x in numbers :
        sum += x
    return(sum / len(numbers))


def mean(self, arg):
    if isinstance(arg, list) or isinstance(arg, tuple):
        return mean_iter(arg)
    elif isinstance(arg, pd.DataFrame):
        return arg.mean()
```

Note that here you have to call `mean((1,2,3))` instead of `mean(1,2,3)`.

You can also use this solution using `*arg` in this way:

```py
import pandas as pd


def mean_iter(numbers):
    sum = 0
    for x in numbers:
        sum += x
    return sum / len(numbers)


def mean(self, *arg):
    first_element = arg[0]
    if isinstance(first_element, list):
        return mean_iter(first_element)
    elif isinstance(first_element, int):
        return mean_iter(arg)
    elif isinstance(first_element, pd.DataFrame):
        return first_element.mean()
```

In this case `arg` is a tuple in any case, then we have to check the inner elements.

So you have the `mean` function whose scope is to call the carrect function based on the argument type. You just have to call `mean()` function, without take care of details.

2. The other solution is to use default params:

```py
def mean(self, arg_iter=None, arg_pandas=None):
    if arg_iter:
        sum = 0
        for x in arg_iter:
            sum += x
        return sum / len(arg_iter)

    elif arg_pandas:
        return arg_pandas.mean()
```

In this solution you have to specify the param name when call function (e.g: `self.mean(arg_iter=[1,2,3])`.